# Symfony Twig Iframe

Tags: php, symfony, iframe, twig

I have project on Symfony and I need to make my project visible in another site with Iframe, I tried:

```
{% if app.request.get('iframe') is not empty %}
<script>
    $(function(){
        window.parent.postMessage({location: window.location}, "*");
    });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

But how see this script for all get url add &iframe=1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
{% if app.request.get('iframe') is not empty %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: ok. then I need add to my get url iframe=1? like  http://mydomen/somerout?iframe=1 ?

Comment: No, my anwser is about the first question (before edit), i translate your code in twig, so with your old code i supposed you have something in your GET['iframe'].

Comment: Thks for your return. :)